# Crear archivo serializable una unica vez en java

Tags: java, serialización

Mi problema es que deseo crear un objeto de tipo Sistema únicamente la primera vez que inicio el programa, las siguientes veces lo que quiero hacer es leer el archivo de Sistema guardado.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sistema sistema;
        try {
            sistema = new Sistema();

            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("archivo_sistema.txt");
            BufferedOutputStream bf = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream obj = new ObjectOutputStream(bf);

            obj.writeObject(sistema);
            obj.flush();
            obj.close();

            FileInputStream recuperar_file = new FileInputStream("archivo_sistema.txt");
            BufferedInputStream bi = new BufferedInputStream(recuperar_file);
            ObjectInputStream obs = new ObjectInputStream(bi);

            sistema = (Sistema)(obs.readObject());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrameMenu vMenu = new JFrameMenu(sistema);

        vMenu.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que tienes con tu código?

Comment: El problema es que en este código claramente no se crea una única vez el objeto Sistema, se crea uno nuevo cada vez que se ejecuta el main, no se como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿este `main()` que vemos aquí es el princpial del programa? Si es así, el objeto, (aunque técnicamente se crea dos veces), existirá una única instancia durante la ejecución de todo el programa, por lo que francamente no entiendo tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

¿Guardado dónde? Durante la ejecución del programa, la variable sistema queda en la memoria heap. Cuando el programa finaliza, estos datos dejan de existir. Por lo tanto, si terminas la ejecución del programa y vuelves a lanzarlo, la variable sistema ya no está en ningún sitio, hasta que vuelve a ser definida. Si quieres conservarla, tienes que guardarla en algún sitio: caché, base de datos...